# mpl_finance plotting an ugly blob rather than candlesticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a candlestick chart in python using `mpl_finance`,

I'm not getting a nice plot, but rather an ugly blob looking like this:

[image]

this is my code:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc

#  candles looks like this: 
#  [DatetimeIndex(['2018-11-05 11:00:00', '2018-11-05 12:00:00',
#         '2018-11-05 13:00:00', '2018-11-05 14:00:00',
#         '2018-11-05 15:00:00', '2018-11-05 16:00:00',
#         '2018-11-05 17:00:00', '2018-11-05 18:00:00',
#         '2018-11-05 19:00:00', '2018-11-05 20:00:00'],
#        dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None), array([0.9432 , 0.94233, 0.94175, 0.94218, 0.94278, 0.94331, 0.94289,
# 0.94447, 0.94523, 0.94599]), array([0.94328, 0.94245, 0.94268, 0.9428 , 0.94404, 0.94352, 0.94458,
# 0.94534, 0.94608, 0.94619]), array([0.9423 , 0.94169, 0.94173, 0.9417 , 0.94213, 0.94288, 0.94283,
# 0.94387, 0.94515, 0.94504]), array([0.94234, 0.94174, 0.94218, 0.94278, 0.94331, 0.94289, 0.94447,
# 0.94523, 0.94599, 0.94515])]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
dates = mdates.date2num(candles[0].to_pydatetime())

quotes = [tuple([dates[i],
         candles[1][i],
         candles[2][i],
         candles[3][i],
         candles[4][i]]) for i in range(len(dates))] #_1

candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.6)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.tight_layout()

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

I've tried many things but can't figure out what's wrong here, any clues?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you have hourly data; but you plot them with a `width` of 14.4 hours each. `width=1./24` may make more sense, or maybe a bit smaller, like 0.8*1/24

Comment: ahhhh, thanks that was it, width was the only piece of that code I didn't check.. how would I do to modify the thickness of the candles?

Comment: Not sure if this what you're after, but you may set a `linewidth` (in units of points) in addition?

Comment: I figured that the `width` argument was again what I was after, it specifies how 'thick' the candles will be, compared to the horizontal space taken by one day. This means that the candles size will be different if you change the number of candles displayed. to keep the UX constant I'll need to factor in the number of rows in `width`